# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session' multiple app

Tags: django, session, django-settings, django-sessions, django-wsgi

I made a new app for my webapp project using ./manage.py startapp webapplogin.

The templates all works however now I keep getting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session' whenever I try to do anything with request such as logout(request) or login(request, user).

I don't understand what the issue is after about 6 hours of debugging/googling...

Do I need to go back to doing the webapp all in webapp instead of trying to split up the project into apps? The templating works fine as well as linking right now, just the no attribute 'session'...

project structure below

```
app_project
    app_backend
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    static
        static_files
    webapp
        templates
            webapp
                 base.html
                 home.html
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    webapplogin
        templates
            login
                login.html
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
```

project settings below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'webapplogin.apps.LoginConfig',
'webapp.apps.WebappConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.gis',
'django.contrib.humanize',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_backend.wsgi.application'
```

Answer (score 1):

currently on 1.9, Django doesn't recognize the MIDDLEWARE setting. You should use the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the order of the middleware is important.
During the request the Django session middleware must execute first in order to add the session object to the request.

Try the following :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```